# Alias Name in Postgresql with value from select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana, column-alias

I am performing a select query to select time-series values. I select the column with the timestamp and the column with a measured value from two sub-queries that contain the relevant data.

```
SELECT
  t1.measured_value as value,
  t2.time
FROM (
  SELECT measured_value , ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rownum
  FROM time_series_data
) t1
JOIN (
  SELECT time, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rownum
  FROM timestamp_data
) t2 ON t1.rownum = t2.rownum
```

Instead of having the alias as name "value", I want an alias based on an single value that can be selected from another table. Naively it would look something like this:

`t1.measured_value as (select real_alias_name from names where id = someID)`

Which obviously doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve this or do I need a completely different approach?

I have a second table which contains the alias name for my measured time series. I cannot use a static alias name, since the alias should be based on values from a table. I only need it as alias name because I am using Grafana. So if anybody has a suggestion on how to do this in Grafana directly, it would also help. But I cant seem to find a way to select column values from tables for the name attribute there.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases have to be statically defined, but you could select a 3rd column containing the name coming from your second table (although I don't think it would fix your grafana problem).

Comment: Yes, the problem for Grafana is, that the name of the plot has to be the column name of my data.